# Where should I dispose managed object held by a form?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dispose, idisposable

If I have a form that owns managed `IDisposable` objects that need to stay around for the lifetime of the form (i.e. class level members, perhaps a class the wraps and manages a timer for the sake of unit testing), when should I call `Dispose()` on them?

For the sake of the question (to avoid "GC will dispose it for you" type of answers), let's also assume there is additional shutdown logic I need to call, for example:

```
Buffer.Flush()
Buffer.Dispose()
```

I could put it in the existing implementation of the `Dispose()` method in my partial class (`Form.Designer.vb`), but modifying that class is typically frowned upon.

It seems that the `FormClosed` or `Disposed` events would be the best choice. Any reason to chose one over the other?

Comment: If it implements `IDisposable`, you should wrap the creation of the resource with a `using` statement.

Comment: I can't do that if it's class level member that I need to keep around, can I? (editted the question to add this extra info)

Comment: No, you can't do that with fields. It is not clear from your question that this is a field. Please _edit it and clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "proper" way is to move the Dispose() method from the form's Designer.vb file to the form's source code file and edit it.  That's however awkward in the vb.net IDE, it hides that file.  You'd have to click the Show All Files icon to see it.

Using FormClosed is wrong, that will dispose your objects too early when your form is displayed with ShowDialog().  Which may cause ObjectDisposed exceptions when you retrieve the dialog results.

Using the Disposed event is fine.

Answer (score 0):

In C# winforms, I move the implementation of the `Dispose()` method from the designer to the code-behind file. Never had problems with that. I would guess you can do the same in VB.

The only thing that is important is that you keep the code that disposes the `Components` collection.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you should try to release unmanaged resources as soon as you can safely do so, for example using the `using` statement.  It typically makes your application safer to maintain and less prone to deadlocks and other misbehavior related to the lifecycle of the resource, than if you habitually keep the resources available "just in case" or completely unnecessarily.

However, sometimes you need either to "cache" an unmanaged resource for performance reasons, or you even need to keep one for semantic reasons (e.g., some intentional locking schemes for mutual exclusion on UI level).

In these cases, it is a good convention to call `Dispose` from `Dispose` of the parent object; in this case by handling the `Disposed` event.

`FormClosed` is riskier as another handler may prevent the closing from occuring, or parent form's handler code may call methods of this form, and you may end up using a disposed resource.  Add to this the risk of never freeing your resources when `Dispose` is directly called on the whole form.

The main advantage of putting any code to `FormClosed` would be a "saner" operating environment, especially access to the parent form.  This is however rarely needed to dispose an unmanaged resource.